# Audio drift issue. Creating video frames programmatically and syncing with midi/audio in java

Tags: java, audio, video, ffmpeg, midi

I want to create a video that changes to the notes on a midi file. I am recording the midi then outputting it as wav.

In java I read the midi file, create images based on the notes played. I am calculating the time between notes and using this to determine the number of frames with this code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < noteImages.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < frameRate * (noteLengths.get(i) / 1000); j++) {
            videoFrames.add(noteImages.get(i));
            frameCount++;
        }
    }
```

I then use ffmpeg to create the video from the images with audio using this command:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -i pic%05d.png -itsoffset 3 -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -r 24 -shortest -y output.mp4
```

The audio starts okay then gradually goes out of sync. If I use higher fps when creating the images it is less pronounced, but I need to use at least 300fps to get it close and it is still not quite right. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Are your notes uniform in duration?

Comment: There are two different note durations, one type being twice the duration of the other. One is 666.667ms the longer ones are 1333.334ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by 1000 will lead to rounding errors unless the lengths already are a multiple of 1000.

You must round only in the last step of the computation (so that the error is always less than one frame):

```
j < (frameRate * noteLengths.get(i)) / 1000
```

If the values can become larger than 2×10<sup>9</sup>, use a `long` multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I made the mistake of not converting to an int so if the result was 40.01 it would have added an extra frame.